# How to get column contents with WHERE and MAX

Tags: sqlite

I have a `table` from which I want to retrieve the `item` column for the row with the highest `tstamp`, plus a flag of `0` and `item` begins with `PHRASE`. This works:

```
SELECT item FROM table WHERE flag = 0 AND item LIKE "PHRASE%" ORDER BY tstamp DESC LIMIT 1;
```

But is `ORDER BY` the most efficient way to do it, when I’m also using `LIMIT 1`? Sounds like I should just be able to do a `MAX` and be done with it. Indeed I can do so:

```
SELECT item,MAX(tstamp) FROM table WHERE flag = 0 AND item LIKE "PHRASE%";
```

But that also returns the `tstamp` column, *which I don‘t want*. How do we achieve the best of both worlds?

Comment: How about: `SELECT item FROM (SELECT item,MAX(tstamp) FROM table WHERE flag = 0 AND item LIKE "PHRASE%")` to remove that 2nd column?

Comment: Didn’t think to stack `FROM`s. That, works, thank you. Would you add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: It's fine. This is a simple refinement of your code.